# Query State is not working with cockroachDB and .net Dapr Client

Tags: c#, cockroachdb, dapr

### Expected Behavior

Query should retrieve the stored record.

### Actual Behavior

Query doe not return any records.

### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

Store the state as below

```
string id = "2";  // Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string key = $"Api-{tenant}-{id}";
var api = new a { 
    b = "c"
};
await _daprClient.SaveStateAsync<a>(StoreName, key, api);
await _daprClient.SaveStateAsync<string>(StoreName, "2b", JsonSerializer.Serialize(api));
```

Retrieving state works fine:
`var x = (await _daprClient.GetStateAsync<a>(StoreName, "Api--2"));`

However, query state always return no record:

```
var q = "{" +
    "\"filter\": {" +
        "\"EQ\": { \"value.b\": \"c\" }" +
    "}" +
"}";
//var q = "{" +
//    "\"filter\": {" +
//        "\"EQ\": { \"b\": \"c\" }" +
//    "}" +
//"}";

var queryResponse = await _daprClient.QueryStateAsync<a>(StoreName, q);
foreach (var entry in queryResponse.Results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"value: {entry.Data.b}");
}
```

The data stored in database is binary:

```
            key           |                     value                      | isbinary | etag |          insertdate           |          updatedate
--------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------
  api-manager-api||2b     | "IntcdTAwMjJiXHUwMDIyOlx1MDAyMmNcdTAwMjJ9Ig==" |   true   |    2 | 2022-09-13 18:58:40.340341+00 | 2022-09-13 19:01:44.954366+00
  api-manager-api||Api--1 | "eyJiIjoiYyJ9"                                 |   true   |    1 | 2022-09-13 18:23:42.650024+00 | NULL
  api-manager-api||Api--2 | "eyJiIjoiYyJ9"                                 |   true   |    2 | 2022-09-13 18:58:40.265943+00 | 2022-09-13 19:01:43.017007+00`
(3 rows)
```

Even after I managed to store the json into cockroachDB but the query with EQ: {"b", "c" } or EQ: {"value.b", "c"} still returns nothing.

```
            key            |                     value                      | isbinary | etag |          insertdate           |          updatedate
---------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------
  api-manager-api||123     | "eyJiIjoiYyJ9"                                 |   true   |    2 | 2022-09-13 21:31:30.087913+00 | 2022-09-13 21:48:09.140251+00
  api-manager-api||2b      | "IntcdTAwMjJiXHUwMDIyOlx1MDAyMmNcdTAwMjJ9Ig==" |   true   |    2 | 2022-09-13 18:58:40.340341+00 | 2022-09-13 21:48:09.114109+00
  api-manager-api||444     | "IntcdTAwMjJiXHUwMDIyOlx1MDAyMmNcdTAwMjJ9Ig==" |   true   |    2 | 2022-09-13 21:37:57.557071+00 | 2022-09-13 21:48:09.150479+00
  api-manager-api||Api--1  | "eyJiIjoiYyJ9"                                 |   true   |    1 | 2022-09-13 18:23:42.650024+00 | NULL
  api-manager-api||Api--2  | "eyJiIjoiYyJ9"                                 |   true   |    2 | 2022-09-13 18:58:40.265943+00 | 2022-09-13 21:48:09.072631+00
  api-manager-api||order_3 | "eyJiIjoiYyJ9"                                 |   true   |    2 | 2022-09-13 21:01:16.154948+00 | 2022-09-13 21:19:28.855963+00
  api-manager-api||test1   | "{\\"b\\":\\"c\\"}"                            |  false   |    1 | 2022-09-13 21:48:09.160417+00 | NULL
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Im having the same issue with mongo db as data store, have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of problem, there could be a few underlying problems. One of the things I noticed with your approach is that you don't have the outer `query` object specified in the request:

[image]

Give this a try.

How I found it? I looked at the unit tests for the client:

https://github.com/dapr/dotnet-sdk/blob/master/test/Dapr.Client.Test/StateApiTest.cs#L1047